# Converting WPF to Web

Tags: asp.net, wpf, xaml, infragistics

My application is built into WPF using Infragistics control(xaml).

I wanted to port the existing app into Web but we don't want to use silverlight(for silverlight we need plugin to be available in our browser and target users will not be having permission to install any plugin into their browser) is there any third part control available which helps us to port our WPF pages into WEB faster.

Comment: never tried, but I don't know if this works? http://www.cshtml5.com/

Comment: Uno Platform does exactly this and you will be able to reuse most of your code - https://platform.uno

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to port WPF to web:

1. Silverlight (which you said you can't use) and
2. [WPF XAML Browser Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx)

Those are the only options I'm aware of.

If you want to convert your WPF app to ASP.NET Web forms or MVC you would have to do it manually. To make it easier you could create shared code which can be used by both WPF and the web application.

If you've followed the MVVM pattern in the WPF project that will make your job a lot easier as you can re-use the view model in MVC (with minor changes)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.In our WPF project we have used MVC pattern.I know i've to do it manually, we don't want to keep WPF app alive.Do we have any third part control available that will reduce my work for creation of pages into Web?

Comment: In terms of converting XAML to HTML I believe there are a number of parsers which you can find by doing a simple search, this is one of them - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa972129(v=vs.90).aspx. I'm not sure about the quality of conversions done by these type of parsers but it should definitely help reduce the manual work

Comment: I saw the link for option second it looks fine any idea for number of simultaneous users who are hitting this app from web URL....