# Migrating a WPF application to HTML5 application

Tags: angular, reactjs, xamarin, asp.net-core, openfin

I am having a wpf application with lot of complex Telerik controls like GRID,DropeDowwn etc. But now we are migrating from WPF to openfin in our organisation. My understanding is we cannot host a wpf application inside a OpenFin container.So, we decided to migrate the WPF application to some Web technologies. Want to know what is the best path for the conversion of WPF to a Web app. What technology should I used so that the conversion of XAML to HTML5 is fast or less time taking

We have checked React, Angular options and for every technologies we feel like we need to re-write the entire UI in HTML 5.

Want to know if there is a easy way of converting a wpf to web application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting WPF to Web](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14661534/5535245).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, XBAP and silverlight, but both of them are pretty old and unsupported. You would likely have quite a bit of trouble getting them working in a modern browser or openfin.

*Silverlight* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Silverlight) - Something similar to Adobe Flash - a plugin that can run xaml apps in the browser. Silverlight is a subset of WPF, so you would probably need changes to your application to work.

*XBAP* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications) allows you to run WPF on the web. It wont run across the internet and only works on windows machines with the .NET framework installed. There are also some restrictions in what you can do with it.

I have to stress that both of these technologies are effectively dead and its really not a good idea to use them. You will find telerik controls for both, but the versions will be outdated.

Telerik does have JavaScript libraries, which would probably ease the transition somewhat - the concepts should be largely similar. Aside from that JS frameworks are very different to WPF.